# Separate all merged Contacts Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, outlook

I am creating a Bluetooth sync application with Outlook Express. All of the work has been done fantastically well but I have one small problem left. When I sync my contacts from Outlook to Android it merges the contacts with similar names. For instance, if I have two contacts called "Najhi" and "Najhi Ullah" then after syncing they will be merged in Android under one name "Najhi". Is there any solution to separate all merged contacts programmatically?

Comment: Its a common and a very know problem. I found this app to be useful. It demerges all your contacts. http://www.hanheide.net/2013/02/new-app-to-separate-accidentally-joined.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own if anyone have the same problem, they can find this post.

```
  private void separate_merged_contacts(){
    Cursor cur1 = obj.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{"_id"} , null, null,null);
    Cursor cur_raw;
    ArrayList<String> raw_contact_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
        raw_contact_id.clear();
        ops.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < cur1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        cur_raw = obj.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID}, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID+"=?",new String[]{cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))} , null);
        while(cur_raw.moveToNext()){
            for (int i = 0; i < cur_raw.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                raw_contact_id.add(cur_raw.getString(cur_raw.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID)));
            }
        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<raw_contact_id.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<raw_contact_id.size();j++)
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE,AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE)
                        .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1,Integer.parseInt(raw_contact_id.get(i)))
                        .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2,Integer.parseInt(raw_contact_id.get(j))).build());
                try {
                    obj.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solutions. the web don't have much examples on the usage of aggregationExceptions

Comment: This code is so unreadable, poorly written and inefficient but I think I can make something with it.
Why do you create a batch of 1 operation and apply it immedatly for example?

Answer (score 1):

While inserting the contact itself you can add one more content value
You can set RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE as  RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED

For more details see :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

Comment: I dit this but it does not help very much. I even disabled aggegration on a contacts group but still they can get aggegrated :(

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet in the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7063235/4957915) certainly gets the job done, but I see 2 problems with it.

1) We are creating unnecessary entries to AggregationExceptions table. If we have 1,000 raw contacts, then we'll end up with 1,000,000 entries. Any phones manufactured within the last few years should be able to handle it without skipping a beat, but it's still a waste.

2) More importantly, once the contacts are separated, you may or may not be able to merge those contacts again, depending on how the entries are entered. The only way to remedy such a problem is to delete the unmerge-able contact and recreate it.

A better approach is to update only the existing AggregationExceptions entries.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
// Get all entries in AggregationExceptions.
cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);

for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE);
    int type = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1);
    long rawContactId1 = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2);
    long rawContactId2 = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
            ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE);  // <--
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, rawContactId1);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, rawContactId2);
    operations.add(builder.build());
}
cursor.close();

if (!operations.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that Android performs contact aggregation (i.e. merging) automatically when the contacts are similar to each other: 2 contacts having the same display name, for example. In that case, there won't be an AggregationExceptions entry for those merged contacts. It's automatic.

If you merge 2 contacts manually using Contacts app, then a new AggregationExceptions entry will be added with TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER, but nothing will be changed to the raw contacts themselves. If you manually separate the merged contacts, then the entry with TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER will be marked as deleted and a new entry with TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE will be added. Keep in mind that once an entry is added, it will be there until the corresponding contact is deleted, because AggregationExceptions doesn't support "delete" operation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Improved code from the answer of [najhi ullah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879931/najhi-ullah) worked like charm for me.

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    if (contentResolver != null) {
        Cursor contactCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id"}, null, null, null);
        if (contactCursor != null) {
            ArrayList<String> rawContactIds = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
            while (contactCursor.moveToNext()) {
                rawContactIds.clear();
                ops.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < contactCursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    Cursor cursorRawContact = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID}, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))}, null);
                    if (cursorRawContact != null) {
                        while (cursorRawContact.moveToNext()) {
                            rawContactIds.add(cursorRawContact.getString(cursorRawContact.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID)));
                        }
                        for (String rawContactId : rawContactIds) {
                            for (String rawContactId2 : rawContactIds) {
                                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE, ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE)
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, Integer.parseInt(rawContactId))
                                        .withValue(ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, Integer.parseInt(rawContactId2)).build());
                            }
                            try {
                                contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        cursorRawContact.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            contactCursor.close();
        }
    }
```